# Linear PDE with constant coefficients number of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Lets say we have a linear PDE of n.order with constant coefficients. Is there a way to count the number of linearly independent solutions similar to an ordinary differential equation.

Comment: It depends strongly on the equation.. consider the generic evolution equation for an elliptic operator, then there is always a unique solution (given very weak requirements on the parameters). On the other hand the Dirichelet problem for the Laplace equation very rarely has a solution